# Is there a way for me to "persist" data on an expressjs app?

Tags: node.js, express

guys! 
I got an expressjs application, an app service. On one of my routers the user will be redirected to another server(e.g: monkeyserver), some data is sent to monkeyserver (a random value, a url to send the user back to my expressjs application and some other stuff). The monkeyserver will send me back that random value so I can check if we are still friends.

So the doubt here is that random value variable(e.g: me_var). What's the simplest way for me to save that me_var so when the user is sent back to my app I can check if me_var value is still the same.

Comment: Do you want to keep unique value for each request or you want to keep a hash value which is valid for few mins?

Comment: @notionquest For each request.

Comment: A database maybe ?

Comment: @TGrif I was hopping there's a way to do it without using it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand the exact circumstances you're describing.  If you have a way to identify a given http request as belonging to a particular user (session cookie created at user login is the usual way to do this), then you can store information for a particular user in a session store that is tied to the session cookie.  Then, sometime later when the user returns, you can still access that same data that corresponds to that user.  A session store may be long term persistent (database) or it may be shorter term only (memory store), depending upon how you implement your own session storage.

So, for your random value that will come back to you later in an URL, you can just store the original in the session store.  Then, when the user comes back, that route they come back to can check the value in the URL (presumably as a query parameter) and compare it to the value in the session store to see if they still match and you can then act accordingly.

Comment: Thx, mate! Cookies will do it and It's still better than adding a little database for those variables.

Comment: @panzerkovic - If you're putting the actual value in the cookie (instead of just a sesssion key), then you may have to take appropriate security concerns so the cookie value can't be forged by an adventurous client.

Comment: Oh, thanks, again! I built a cipher method on both sides. So it's kind of safe as a palliative solution.

Comment: @panzerkovic -  A cipher on the client side is not safe, it's fully visible to anyone.

Comment: Once again, thank you for your help. Truth is. We are actually building a mobile app(e.g: Baleia). Our client's database API has been built by other guys (e g:  fisk). To a baleia's user access fisk's data, it has to be authenticated, the method chosen was oauth2, by fisk's team I guess. So we had to build an app service (e.g: same). Earlier, by both sides cipher I meant on baleia and on same. We use appcelerator, which has a mongodb like cloud pre built database. I suggested using it to save: tokens, that random value and the token payload, it'd be safe. Manager was not into it.

Comment: So these things are being passed via cookie to our baleia app. A webview inside baleia get the cookies decoded and cipher it for our precious data. :/